# Connect SQL Server use python and return in table of data

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I try to use `pyodbc` package to create a stored procedure connect SQL Server in python, and yes I can connect it.

The code I use like this :

```
server = '(LocalDb)\LocalDBDemo'
database = 'Test'

try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                          'SERVER=' + server + ';'
                          'DATABASE=' + database + ';'
                          'trusted_connection=yes;'
                           )
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    df = []
    storedProcedure = "Exec [dbo].[get_Movie]"
    cursor.execute(storedProcedure)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    df.append(row)
    
    while row:
        df.append(row)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
         
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    print(df)
    
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: %s" % e)
```

the result will be

```
                                     0
0  [Bulleftproof 2, Movie, 2020-01-09]
1  [Bulleftproof 2, Movie, 2020-01-09]
2         [Street Food, TV show, None]
3         [Movie_1, Movie, 2020-02-07]
4         [Movie_2, Movie, 2020-04-09]
5        [Show_1, TV show, 2020-04-01]
```

but how to get the result `df` like this:

```
      Movie_Title Movie_Type  Date_added
0  Bulleftproof 2      Movie  2020-01-09
1     Street Food    TV show        None
2         Movie_1      Movie  2020-02-07
3         Movie_2      Movie  2020-04-09
4          Show_1    TV show  2020-04-01
```

I already tried `pd.read_sql_query` using SQL syntax load table, it could return like above result, but my real SQL query is large, when the large query into `pd.read_sql_query`, it would be error so I think it contains the indent problem, maybe other useful function?

Any advice? Appreciate it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You are attempting to retrieve the results from the SP row-by-row using `.fetchone()` and appending those rows to the DataFrame. However, you say that using `.read_sql_query()` is "[not] recommend[ed]" when that will accomplish exactly the same thing, just in a more efficient way. Please [edit] your question to clarify your concerns.

Comment: Hi @GordThompson, I edit the question, appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gord Thompson 's remind that was doing the same thing, I directly used the query in `.read_sql_query()` function, and it works! The code modified like this,

```
server = '(LocalDb)\LocalDBDemo'
database = 'Test'

try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                          'SERVER=' + server + ';'
                          'DATABASE=' + database + ';'
                          'trusted_connection=yes;'
                           )
    SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query("Exec [dbo].[get_Movie]", cnxn)
    df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query)
    print(df)
    
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: %s" % e)
```

I think I'm not clear about how to use SQL in python script, and appreciate the advice.

Comment: `pd.read_sql_query()` already returns a DataFrame, so you can just do `df = pd.read_sql_query( … )`